# Downgrading Homebrew's default Java version

Tags: java, macos, sbt, homebrew

Recently i used brew upgrade and now my sbt seems to be using bersion 16 java, i cant actually find this version on my machine and need to set it back to java version 8 that is on my laptop. I have two questions:

1. Whats going on here how is it using version 16 when my laptop doesnt seem to have it?
2. How do i get my sbt to using java version 8 again?

Comment: Clarify "Doesn't seem to have it"? `java -version` or `echo $JAVA_HOME` should show the value.

Answer (score -1):

I would expect SBT to work fine with Java 16, and be able to compile your code to Java 8, if needed.

In any case, [`brew install openjdk@8`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk@8#default)

Alternatively, don't use homebrew to manage JVM things, and try https://sdkman.io

Comment: that doesn't work as mentioned jdk 8 is already installed

Comment: You can either forcibly set `JAVA_HOME` to the JDK 8 path on disk (which is what sdkman will do), or you can uninstall the java 16 with homebrew since `openjdk@8` will not update to 16 with `brew upgrade`.

Comment: as mentioned i cannot find version 16 on my laptop, using /usr/libexec/java_home -V shows only the 1.8 jdk on my laptop. If you have a command that will surley get rid of it i can try it.

Comment: I don't know where you have homebrew installing things to... By default, `/usr/local/Cellar` or `/usr/local/Caskroom` for casks. Search under there for folder with `jdk`, `jre` or `java` in the name